If I toss a coin for many hours during 50 years, what is the maximum longest streak of tails in a row can I expect?
Let's say by realistic chance I mean the getting it 50% at least once. And I make 10.000 tosses a day. How can I calculate the streak length - at least roughly and approximately?

You might have better luck asking this on the math substack.

I’m voting to close this question because belongs to maths, not philosophy

Also there are online calculatora for this, like https://www.omnicalculator.com/statistics/coin-flip-streak

Use the universe to calculate it: record the longest streak you get by doing the experiment. That's what scientists do :-) ask Albert Michaelson

10000 tosses x 365 days x 50 years  ~ 200,000,000 tries. Take the log_2 of that and you receive ~27.x so round up to 28. So 1/(2^28)x200,000,000 is ~1. Now I leave it to the math.stackexchange to do the hypotheses test for the 50% accuracy. But yeah don't expect streaks longer than 28.

52 equal tosses in a row is about as likely as winning the lottery. If a billion people do it, someone getting 82,equal tosses is about as likely as winning the lottery

I'll be damned. This site has an app provides an analysis that is very close to what you are after. The references used to create this calculation are listed at the end.http://shiny.calpoly.sh/Longest_Run/

I guess this is why people invented math: all that coin tossing cut in to getting other things done :-)

UPDATE: Thanks to @causative for setting me straight on a fatal flaw in my calculations below.  I was getting tripped up on the fact that the coin is truly independent and random on each toss, and each "slice" of data is completely random taken alone (with equal probabilities of each permutation); however, there are still "interactions" between these "slices" when calculating total probability, because of the overlapping nature of the samples.  (I.e., given that none of the previous slices has resulted in a streak already, the odds the next toss will, on that premise, is reduced in complex ways, because the previous slices overlapped.)  Anyway, see link by @causitive for more information ans using a Markov chain for a proper calculation: math.stackexchange.com/questions/383704/probability-of-streaks.  I believe the answer below still gets within the general ballpark, though, in that you have a realistic expectation of 28 heads, though less optimistically than 49%.

You can expect a 49% probability of having a streak of 28 heads.
The number of days would be 365.25 * 50, or 18,263 (rounding up).  Thus the total number of coin tosses is 10k * 18,263, or 182,630,000.  The probability of getting a streak of heads of n on any particular arrangement is 1 / 2^n; and so for example, the odds of getting 28 heads in a row is 1 / 2^28, or 1 in 268,435,456.  Inversely, the odds of not getting that streak on any particular arrangement is 1 - (1 / 2^n), or for 28, or ~0.999999996.  Since the number of total 28-length permutations in this case is 182,629,973 (182,630,000 - 27), the odds of all of these permutations not being 28 heads in a row is ~0.999999996 ^ 182,629,973, 0.506439876, or about 51%; which means the odds of getting 28 heads in a row is a little above 49%.  So put a little more generally, the odds of getting a streak of heads of n length, with x number of flips, is 1 - ((1 - (1 / 2^n))^(x - n + 1)) (and putting the entire equation into my calculator avoids the rounding errors of doing each step separately).
I was surprised at how low the streak number was, but a quick intuitive confirmation of 2^28 = 268,435,456, which is significantly higher than the number of total sequences in this case, is in line with those odds!  I guess that's a demonstration (for me at least) of the ungraspable nature of large exponential numbers and diminishing probability.

"the odds of all of these permutations not being 28 heads in a row is ~0.999999996 ^ 182,629,973" This would only be true if each 28-length flip sequence was independent of all the others, which is not the case.

@causative For probabilistic calculations I don't think that matters, though, since you can calculate the probability of each sequence independently and then multiply them together, which in effect takes all that into account.

You can't just multiply probabilities unless they are independent, which in this case they are not. Your answer is wrong. There are right ways to calculate this involving a Markov chain.

@causative Is it possibly a misunderstanding of conditional probability of the source vs. the overlapping nature of the samples measured?  The randomness of the source is independent with each toss, even when overlapping samples are measured, and so I'm not seeing how this is incorrect...do you have a link to something that would give what you would consider an accurate probability in this case, that I could compare?  Wouldn't Markov apply only if the probability of each toss depended on prior state?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383704/probability-of-streaks

Thanks @causative, looks like you're right.  My calculation is what one of the answers called the "naive" calculation.  I'll delete this answer until I have a chance to look into this a little more.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
